# Assert.assertAllValuesInArrayAreEqual - unit testing in java using junit, there is no such method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Or is there ?

I just have

```
int[] results
```

and want to check each element in array has the same int value.

(yeah I could just loop through them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to loop, just convert the array into a Set object and then check its length, if the length is 1 then everything in the array was equal.

```
    Integer[] myArray = ...;
    assertThat(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(myArray)).size(), is(1));
```